# How to undo git rm --cached <filename>?

Tags: git

After staging a file(tracked file) I realized it needed some changes, so to unstage it I used
`git rm --cached <filename>`. Consequently, I lost all the changes. Is there a way to undo it?

Comment: `gir rm --cached` does _not_ unstage a file in Git, it unstages the addition of that file to the repository.  What changes did you lose, and are you certain that you really lost anything?

Answer (score 10):

`git rm --cached` only removes the new file from the index and not from the working tree. Be careful doing it that way. If this was an existing file you just staged the deletion of the file.

You can add it again with `git add <filename>`.

A more common way of unstaging changes is to use `git reset HEAD <filename>`.

But... it's not necessary to unstage a file to add further changes. You can just make further changes and stage those again using `git add <filename>`.

Answer (score 2):

Git's use of the phrase *staged changes* or *to stage some changes* can get very confusing.

To avoid getting confused, here is what you need to know:

- Git has a thing that Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or sometimes—rarely now—the *cache*.  These three names all refer to one single thing.  Here, I'll just call it the index.
- The index initially contains a copy<sup>1</sup> of *each file* that is in the commit that you checked out.  (This current commit is also called `HEAD`.)  These files are in a Git-only format.  **You can't see these files.**  (This is a slight overstatement—there are some special Git tricks to see them—but normally they're invisible.)  The files that you *can* see are in your *work-tree*, which holds ordinary everyday files.
- When you make your *next* commit, Git will use the files that are in the index at that time.  That is, when you run `git commit -m "some message"` (or after `git commit` without `-m` collects a message from you), Git will then, at that time, package up all the files that are in the index *at that time*, and use those to make the new commit.
- Hence, if you've changed or replaced a file in your work-tree, you must first *copy it back into the index*.  Otherwise Git will just re-use the original file.

When you run `git add file`, Git takes the work-tree copy, compresses it into the special Git-only format, and stuffs the compressed copy into the index.  Now the index copy no longer matches the `HEAD` copy, but it does match the work-tree copy.

If you change the work-tree copy *again*, now all three copies are different!  At this point `git status` will tell you that you have "changes staged for commit" and also "changes *not* staged for commit".

You can change the work-tree copy to anything at any time.  This has no effect on the index copy.

You can *remove* the work-tree copy without removing the index copy, using any tool on your computer that removes a file.  You can also remove the *index* copy without removing the work-tree copy, using `git rm --cached`.  And, you can remove *both* copies using `git rm`.  None of this affects any existing commit—no existing commit can *ever* be changed!  But removing the index copy does affect the *next* commit, because when you run `git commit`, Git will package up all the files that are in the index at that time, so if the file is *gone* from the index, it won't be in the *next* commit.

Since what's in the index is what will be in the next commit, that's a pretty good description of the index:  **The index is, mostly anyway, what will go in your next commit.**  The index does have some additional roles to play, especially during merges, but we won't cover those here at all.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the index actually holds references to the copies.  But the effect is pretty much the same as if the index held actual copies, at least until you start diving into how to manipulate the index directly using `git update-index`.

---

#### How to "unstage changes"

To get the file from the current (`HEAD`) commit back into the index *in the form it has in the current commit*, you can use `git reset -- file`.  The `--` here is only needed if the file name resembles a `git reset` option or a branch name.  For instance, if you have a file named `master` *and* a branch name `master`, `git reset master` looks like you want to use the *branch* name, so you must write `git reset -- master` to tell git that you mean the *file* `master`.

So: **`git reset -- file` copies the file from the `HEAD` commit into the index**.  This is true even if you *removed* the index copy: reset will just put it back.  It's also true if the file *isn't* in the `HEAD` commit.  If you've added file `F` to the index, and then decide it should not be in the index after all, you can `git reset -- F` and that *removes* it from the index.

(You can also `git rm --cached F` if you prefer: that has the same effect at this point.  But if you just want to make the index copy match the `HEAD` copy, use `git reset` because that works for both cases: there *is* a `HEAD` copy, or there isn't.)

#### How do you know what is staged?

Again, you can't actually *see* the copy of the file that is in your index.  So how do you know whether it matches some other copy?  The answer is: `git status` tells you, in a short and useful way.

Let's say you have three files in your *work-tree* called `README.md`, `main.py`, and `util.py`.  The first two of these files came out of the `HEAD` commit, and you've just created `util.py` yourself now, so it's *not* in the `HEAD` commit and *not* in the index.

The `git status` command runs *two* comparisons:

- First, it compares every file in `HEAD` to every file in the index.  So this compares `HEAD:README.md` (the HEAD copy) to `:README.md` (the index copy).<sup>2</sup>  Then it compares `HEAD:main.py` to `:main.py`.

  For each file that is *the same*, `git status` says *nothing*.

  For each file that is *different*, `git status` says that there are *changes staged for commit*.  If the file is completely gone from the index, you've staged a delete.  If the file in the index is totally new, you've staged a newly-added file.

  So, if you know what was in the `HEAD` commit, you now know which files are the same in the index: *anything `git status` did not mention*.
- Next, having told you what's different or not in `HEAD` vs index, `git status` goes on to compare each file in the index to each file in the work-tree.  So here, it will compare `:README.md` to `README.md`, `:main.py` to `main.py`, and discover that there's a `util.py` that's not in the index.

  For each file that is *the same*, `git status` says *nothing*.

  For each file that is *different*, `git status` reports changes *not* staged for commit.  That's right because `git commit` isn't going to use the work-tree, it's just going to use the index.

  For a file like `util.py`, that's in the work-tree but *not* in the index, `git status` reports it as an *untracked file*.  That's what an untracked file is: a file that is in the work-tree, but not in the index.

Note that if you *remove* a file from the index, it is instantly untracked!  If you `git add` the file so that it's in the index, well, now it's tracked.

---

<sup>2</sup>This funny `HEAD:file` and `:file` syntax is specific to Git itself, and only works with *some* Git commands.  One of those is `git show`: you actually *can* see the index copy of `README.md` using `git show :README.md`, for instance.  Since `git show` is a user-oriented command, you can do this with pretty good safety: `git show HEAD:file`, `git show :file`, and `git show <commit:>file` are all pretty good ways to see a specific copy of a specific file that's been turned into its internal Git form, either saved in a commit, or ready to go into a commit.

You can also see the names of all the index copies of files using `git ls-files`.  In a big repository, this prints a *lot* of names!  It is not meant for normal everyday use and is not a very user-friendly command, though.

---

#### Commits *read* the index; `git checkout` *writes* to it

To make a new commit, you simply copy the right files into the index and run `git commit`.  The index *already has* all the files from the *current* commit, so you only need to update any files that you want to be different, or add any new files you want, or remove any files you want to delete.  Then you `git commit` and make a *new* commit.  This new commit is now the `HEAD` commit, and now the `HEAD` commit and the index match.

If the `HEAD` commit and the index match, and those two match the work-tree, then everything is "clean" and you can easily switch to another commit, using, e.g.:

```
git checkout otherbranch
```

(or the new Git 2.23 `git switch` command, which is like a friendly variant of `git checkout branch` that doesn't have all the other Git tools shoved into one command—`git checkout` can do somewhere between three and seven different jobs, depending on how you count).

This checkout, assuming it succeeds,<sup>3</sup> has to:

1. fill your index with all the files from the tip of `otherbranch` (and remove any irrelevant ones);
2. fill your work-tree with all the files from the tip of `otherbranch` (and remove any irrelevant ones); and
3. make the name `HEAD` refer to the tip commit of `otherbranch`.

Once that's all done, your `HEAD` commit, index, and work-tree again all match.

---

<sup>3</sup>The `git checkout` command can *sometimes* succeed *even if the index and work-tree are not "clean".  Clean is a poorly defined term here, but to see more about when `git checkout` will let you switch branches while carrying modifications, see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

---

#### Conclusion

You can't *see* the index copies of files!  What you can and should do is use `git status`, which *compares* the `HEAD` files to the index copies.  In a big project, with hundreds, thousands, or even millions of files, Git will *say nothing* about almost all of them.  It will only mention the ones that are *different*.  That's much more useful.

Whenever your `HEAD`, index, and work-tree all match, `git status` says *nothing*.  When `git status` sees some things that don't match, it prints file names under *changes staged for commit* and/or under *changes not staged for commit* depending on whether it's the `HEAD` and index copies that disagree, or the index and work-tree copies that disagree, or both.

`git add` copies files into the index.  If they were already there before, well, now they're overwritten with the copy from the work-tree.  If they weren't there before, well, now they are.

`git rm` removes files from the index.  Without `--cached`, it *also* removes the same files from the work-tree.  With `--cached`, it leaves the work-tree copies alone—which is fine for *now*, but a later `git checkout` might need to remove the work-tree copies!

Git will, in general, try fairly hard not to destroy any work-tree files with precious data.  [What's "precious", though?](https://tenor.com/search/my-precious-gifs)  Well, if work-tree file `util.py` has been added and committed and matches `HEAD:util.py` and `:util.py`, at this point, `util.py` is *not* precious any more, because if you want it, it's there in the commit.  So you can `git checkout` an old commit that *doesn't* have `util.py` and Git will feel totally safe in removing `util.py` from your work-tree.  Just `git checkout` the latest command it's back.

Some Git commands, including `git reset --hard`, *will* destroy work-tree files.  The theory behind `git reset --hard` is that you *want* to reset both the index *and* your work-tree.  The default mode, which is `git reset --mixed`, resets only the index copies.<sup>4</sup>  That's why `git reset -- file` "un-stages" the file—copies `HEAD:file` into `:file`–but doesn't touch the work-tree copy of `file`.

---

<sup>4</sup>Peculiarly, `git reset --soft`, `git reset --mixed`, and `git reset --hard` only allow you do do *every* file.  When you want to do just one file, using `git reset -- file`, it always uses `--mixed`.  For other cases, you have to use one of the many alternate modes of `git checkout`.  Git 2.23 introduces a new command, `git restore`, that is intended to make this less confusing.  Time will tell whether it does: `git restore` is technically still experimental.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add  again. Here is a sample set of commands.

```
echo testmodify>> FOO //Appends "testmodify" to FOO
git add FOO // Stage FOO to commit
git rm --cached FOO // Unstage FOO
git add FOO // Stage FOO
```

FOO still contains "testmodify"

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience. I ran this command "git rm --cached ."
and my whole project files got removed so before pushing any commit, I stash the code. Simple and easy way to get rid of this issue.

```html
git stash
```